# Document custom properties are not saved in Word desktop

Tags: office-js

My office js Word add-in code saves a custom property to the document customproperty collection. The code for saving is as below.

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    //method accepts property name plus value
    context.document.properties.customProperties.add(propertyname, value);
    context.document.save();
    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Property saved");
        })
        .catch (function (e) {
        console.log("Error occured inserting property " + e.message);

    });
});
```

After my add-in executes I can see the custom property when I click on Info->Properties->AdvancedProperties->Custom. But when i close the Office 365 Word desktop application and reopen the document I find the custom property has not been saved. So I opened the Word document again in desktop and then again ran my add-in.  This time I also typed some characters in the document and then closed the document. Now when I reopened the document I found that the custom properties are saved correctly. This means that custom properties are not getting saved when we execute the word context sync operation.

I then performed the same operation in Office online and it worked perfectly. This means that this issue occurs only in Office 365 Word Desktop. I had faced the same issue in [Aug 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52062904/document-custom-properties-not-save-in-office-365-for-windows). But it looks like the bug still exists.

I am running Word desktop Version 1808 (Build 10730.20304 Click-to-Run)

Comment: I tried to reproduce. If I save the Word document, the custom property is saved. If I close the Word document without saving, the property is not saved. But that's what I'd expect. Word Online has an autosave feature, so that's probably why it works there without explicitly saving.

Comment: I modified the code to include context.document.save(); But even then the custom properties are not saved. Even Word desktop has an autosave feature. This is not a feature but a bug.

Comment: I can't reproduce. The bug that's referred to in your Aug 2018 question is about an unneeded prompt to save. But that is not your symptoms.

Comment: You mentioned that this happened in Aug 2018 - have you updated your Office since/

Comment: Yes my office version has been updated since then.

Comment: Sample application which demonstrates the issue has been posted to [link](https://github.com/codecrasher99/OfficeCustomPropertyBug).

Comment: It seems that the dirty flag doesnt get fired when one adds a custom property to the document.

Comment: I added a blank space at the end of the document and this workaround seems to have solved the problem